# Powershell and Razor Template

Tags: powershell, razor, razorengine, razorgenerator

I'm using PowerShell and [Render-RazorTemplate.ps1](https://github.com/knutkj/misc/blob/master/PowerShell/Razor/Render-RazorTemplate.ps1) to create a html page

I have a 'System.Collections.Hashtable' passing to my Model and i'm not getting this to work

```
@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    <div class="BTC-setting"><i class='fa @(s["Icon"])'></i><span>@s["Name"]</span></div>
}
```

If I use like this

```
class='fa @(s["Icon"])'
```

I have an error like

```
The name 'WriteAttribute' doesn't exist on the actual context
>>> WriteAttribute("class", Tuple.Create(" class=\'", 225), Tuple.Create("\'", 248)**
```

If I remove the **@(s["Icon"])** from inside of the property class it works and shows me the value

Someone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution to my issue, just put **@:** at the begging of the html tags that uses variables inside quotes

ISSUE

```
@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    <div class="BTC-setting"><i class='fa @(s["Icon"])'></i><span>@s["Name"]</span></div>
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    @:<div class="BTC-setting"><i class='fa @(s["Icon"])'></i><span>@s["Name"]</span></div>
}
```